# Same post defaced twice by anonymous user(s)

Tags: discussion

I recently started reviewing Suggested Edits and rejected a couple of edits.

The edits I have rejected (along with users Benedikt Bauer and DWGKNZ) were both vandalism. I am curious that both cases involved the same post. The suggested edits can be seen [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8405) and [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8767).

I have a couple of questions for my more experienced peers.

- Is it common for the same post to be repeatedly defaced?
- Since (to me) this suggests that the same person is the perpetrator, should these events be reported to support, or are such events already being tracked behind the scenes?

If it should be reported to support I'm thinking I only need to add the support tag to this post.

Comment: It does just look like drive-by spam - it's possible that that post comes up on some random keyword search that they're using. Or some other "find all the posts that..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Mσᶎ's "drive-by spam" description is right. The suggested edits were *different* spam and came from different IP addresses. Also, the formatting was wrong (used syntax common to some forums). I'm guessing that it was entirely automated via a botnet.

Basically, there's really nothing we can do about it, other than be sure you always look carefully when reviewing suggested edits.

I thought about using "protect", but that only stops anonymous (and very low rep) answers, not anonymous edit suggestions.